# Issue with Struts2 Filter Exception

Tags: java, struts2

Working on a simple web application at the moment and I cant get my Struts project to work because of:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.InstantiationError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:390)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:274)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:970)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:438)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:482)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>UI-S01</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Im looking for the log files that are given but or some reason they arent being created for this date, past logs are created.

The Jars that I currently have are:
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar

commons-io-2.2.jar

commons-lang3-3.2.jar

commons-logging-1.1.3.jar

commons-validator-1.3.1.jar

freemarker-2.3.22.jar

javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar

mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

ognl-3.0.13.jar

struts2-bootstrap-plugin-1.6.1.jar

struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar

struts2-core-2.3.28.jar

struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.jar

struts2-json-plugin-2.3.28.jar

xwork-core-2.3.28.jar

Comment: Why 2.3.15.1 for convention ? 2.3.28 there too. And for jQuery plugin there's 3.7.1

Comment: Unpredictable version mismatch errors. [How to know a version of Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985333/how-to-know-a-version-of-struts-2).

Comment: Are you laoding your jars with maven or manual ?!