# Struts2 Convention Plugin @Actions not mapping with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

When upgrading my application to use **Spring Boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE** + **struts2-convention-plugin with Struts2-core version 2.5.20** the actions are not being mapped correctly and I am getting the error

> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: There is no
>   Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home] associated with
>   context path [].

If I decalre the actions in `struts.xml` they work perfectly.

Below is my current configuration, why are they not mapping?

I have tried many diffrent configs and nothing seems to work, the `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` is firing but not actions are found, as if Spring has not scanned them. Could this be a dependency version issue?

**application.yaml**

```
  server:
    port: 8080
    servlet:
      context-path: /
```

**Struts2.xml**

```
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.myactions.action" />
        <constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?/myjar.*?jar(!/)?,.*?/myjar*?jar(!/)?" />
        <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
        <constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
        <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="100000000" />
        <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="struts-default"/>

    ## THIS WORKS
    <!--    <package name="home"  extends="struts-default">-->
    <!--        <action name="actionHome" class="com.myactions.action.HomeController" method="actionHome">-->
    <!--            <result name="success">home.jsp</result>-->
    <!--        </action>-->
    <!--    </package>-->

    </struts>
```

**Controller**

```
@Namespace("/")
public class HomeController extends BaseController {

    @Action("home")
    public String actionHome() throws Exception {           
        return SUCCESS;
    }   
}
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
        return springApplicationBuilder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Struts2 Filter**

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class Struts2Filter extends StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter {

}
```

**UPDATE**

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: Probably the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890473/573032

Comment: @Roman C: The dependencies mentioned in that post are all present (see update)

Comment: @cID have you made any progress? I tried downgrading Struts core and plugins to 2.3.37, to no avail: I still can't get rid of struts.xml.

Comment: In addition, it works fine without struts.xml if you package your app as WAR and deploy it in an external Tomcat.

Comment: @Marc Tarin; No luck, I have tried many combinations of struts2-convention-plugin and spring versions, nothing seems to work when scanning

Comment: Just had some luck with embedded jetty. I'll post an answer later today.

Comment: @Marc Tarin: I have fiund why my classes were not being scanned please see update 2

Comment: Answers should be added as answers, not as part of the question. New questions should be new questions, not added to other different questions.

Comment: @cID I saw your update while writing my answer. Guess what, our results are quite similar ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple days of trials and errors, here are a few clues.

Spring Boot 2.1.8 with Struts 2.5.20 configured with struts.xml works.
Your projet POM requires at least the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.20</version>
</dependency>
```

I would also recommend adding the [Config Browser Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) to easily list the available actions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.20</version>
</dependency>
```

It works when you package :

- a fat JAR with an embedded Tomcat server, which is the default behavior
- a [WAR in an external Tomcat Server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy)

To get rid of struts.xml and configure your actions only through Java classes, the [Convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention) is required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Notes :

- the constant defined in struts.xml can also be migrated to the struts.properties file (default values listed [here](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-properties.html))
- struts.xml takes precedence over the Convention plugin and struts.properties

When struts.xml is removed, the Convention plugin takes over and Action classes are mapped using the name of packages and classes. The default conventions (action-to-URL mappings, result path...) can also be overridden thanks to a set of [annotations](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/#annotation-reference).

Still, as mentioned by the OP, configuration through annotations does **NOT** work out of the box with an embedded Tomcat (it does with an external Tomcat, though).

Best I could do so far, is make it work using an [embedded Jetty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) instead of Tomcat, and adding the [recommended configuration](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/#jetty-embedded) to struts.properties:

```
struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader=false
struts.convention.action.fileProtocols=jar,code-source
```

The starting log still shows errors, but I'm able to access the configured actions with no more XML.

**UPDATE**

After the OP's update, I digged in a bit more. It turns out the Convention Plugin works fine with Tomcat embedded and no XML needed, by doing the following:

- Adding the following line to the struts.properties

  ```
  struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader=false
  ```
- Upgrading [asm](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm) modules *asm*, *asm-commons* and *asm-tree* to release 6.2 or later to prevent errors similar to

  ```
  ERROR org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultClassFinder.<init>:95 - Unable to read class [...]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Having stepped through `spring2-convention-plugin` the class `PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder` has a method `buildUrlSet` which gets all the `urls` to classes that need to be scanned for `Actions` this was removing the `urls` to my classes and hence nothing was being scanned.

There is a condition `excludeParentClassLoader` which needs to be set to `false` *(line 415)*.

**Solution**

Set below constant's to -

```
<constant name="struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="jar,code-source" />
```